# Is there something like an in-place version of numpy concatenate?

Tags: numpy

I'd like to be able to concatenate multiple arrays and have changes in the original arrays reflected in the concatenated version. So the code below should not raise an `AssertionError`.

```
arr1 = np.zeros(3)
arr2 = np.zeros(3)
arr3 = np.in_place_concatenate([arr1, arr2])
arr1[0] = 10
assert arr3[0] == 10
```

Does this concept exist in numpy?

Comment: you have to start with `arr3`.  If `arr1` is a `view` of it, the the changes work.

Comment: @hpaulj yes. It's not the most direct way for my exact code but if it's the only way it will have to do. In my code the paradigm is that arr1 and arr2 are specified first.

Comment: I don't think there is one. Expanding an array usually requires copy to a new place. What if `arr1` is a view of another `arr0`? Is `arr1` going to be view of both `arr0` and `arr3`?

Comment: @QuangHoang makes sense. I suppose my magic `in_place_concatenate` method would first check that all the arrays are not views.

Comment: You may need to read some more about how arrays are stored - with focus on `shape` and the underlying databuffer.  Each of your source arrays has its own data.  The concatenate will have its own as well.  It can't reference piecemeal the data of the source arrays.  With `list3 = [list1, list2]`, `list3` has references to the other lists, and thus `list3[0][0]` will reference the same values as `list1[0]`.  Arrays dont do that.

Comment: @hpaulj yes I've just read more into it. Thanks for the pointers. I implemented my own then. It takes the arrays list, uses normal `concatenate` then pulls out the corresponding views from the result of that. The function then returns the concatenation and the views. So the function signature is `in_place_concatenate(List[np.ndarray]) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, List[np.ndarray]]`